# How to make a jButton do one thing at first click and another at second?

Tags: java

When I press the button the first time it's supposed to display a message, but the next time I am to press it it should do it's normal use.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEven evt) {    
  jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+"Let the battle begin!\n");
```

Basically that is what I want it to do at first click, as well as:

```
if (jProgressBar1.getValue() > 0) {
  if (publicInt.rndNum() > 90)
}
```

etc, etc..

EDIT:

This is what I did to make it work, thanks to a commenter.

```
if (publicInt.startPhrase() == true) {
  jTextArea1.setText("The battle has begun!\n");
  publicInt.sp = false;
}
```

Comment: Use a boolean flag ?

Comment: You are omitting interesting parts of code, and the few code you provide has some syntax errors.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley he's new, lets cut him some slack

Comment: That is not the full extension of my code, the code itself works properly, thus i have not found a way to copy the code directly to a code box in this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a boolean, let's say pressed, which will be false, and after pressing the button you set if true... the code will be something like:

```
boolean pressed = false;
private void jButton1ActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEven evt) {

if (!pressed) {
    jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+"Let the battle begin!\n");
    pressed = true;
}
```

Comment: I think you want in the if statement `pressed = true;`

Comment: @ Takendarkk, it's called a if statement, not a loop, and you are right, the code will not work as per the requirements of OP.. should be `pressed=true` in the if statement.